# Check if datepicker is open

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a field with a datepicker. I want know if it is open. I've tried with:

```
$("#filter_date").datepicker( "widget" ).is(":visible")
```

but it returns always true.

How can I check if it's open?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This might be a possible bug in the past. Now this solution

```
$("#filter_date").datepicker( "widget" ).is(":visible")
```

works perfectly

Comment: The first time the datepicker is attached to an element, it is invisible and yet visible returns true. The element doesn't have yet the display none style but it's still hidden, and unfortunately, not detected in your code. Still, +1. :)

Comment: Ahh, on first load, you should check if it's :empty.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Both :empty and :visible always return true - before the first time the datepicker is opened and always afterward.

Comment: beware of the fact that if you have multiple inputs with datepickers bound to them, this will return true when any of them is displayed (it's actually the same div element for all of them), so this actually does not tell if you the datepicker for #filter_date is being active

Answer (score 11):

Simply set:

```
#ui-datepicker-div { display: none; }
```

in your **CSS file** and your code:

```
$("#filter_date").datepicker( "widget" ).is(":visible")
```

will work correctly!

Answer (score 4):

Off the top of my head, I could think of using the [beforeShow](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow) and [onClose](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose) events defined for the datepicker control to toggle a class (or a flag) somewhere, and checking the presence of which to determine whether the datepicker control is open or not.

Answer (score 3):

```
   var isCalendarVisible;     
   $(".datepicker).datepicker().on("show", function () {
          isCalendarVisible = true;
    }).on("hide", function () {
          isCalendarVisible = false;
    });
```

I have used this approach for toggling of date-picker on clicking of a button. `isCalendarVisible` getting updated on 'show' & 'hide' of datepicker accordingly. I check value of 'isCalendarVisible' to open or close it manually .

```
    function toggleCalendar() {
        if (isCalendarVisible) {
            $(".datepicker .add-on").datepicker("hide");
        } else {
            $(".datepicker .add-on").datepicker("show");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Access the datepicker's style attribute and compare it with a style when datepicker is hidden (display: none):

```
var datePickerStyle = $('.datepicker').attr('style');
var noneStyle = 'display: none;';
if(datePickerStyle.indexOf(noneStyle) != -1){
     console.log('shown');
} else {
     console.log('not shown');
}
```

Comment: This one is actually good when you need to test if element is visible, and you run tests on phantomJS (.is(":visible") didn't work for me)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this.

```
$('.inputCalendar').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    monthNames: [ "01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12" ],
    monthNamesShort: [ "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12" ],
    dayNames: [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" ],
    dayNamesShort: ["(Sun)", "(Mon)", "(Tue)", "(Wed)", "(Thur)", "(Fri)", "(Sat)"],
    yearSuffix: ".",
    showMonthAfterYear: true,
    autoSize: true,
    minDate : dateMin(),
    maxDate : dateMax(),
    beforeShow : function(){ //show
        $('.date').addClass('active');          
    },
    onClose: function(){ //hide
        $('.date').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```