# jquery datepicker displaying off a button click, is there a way to determine display state (show/hide)?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'd like to make the button into a toggle but I looked at the docs and couldn't find a isHidden isVisible type of property...

.showCalendar is my button and #weekDate is my input field. Is there a way to get the display state of datepicker?

```
 $('.showCalendar').click(function () {
    $('#weekDate').datepicker("show");
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no way to get the display state of the date picker (apparently, applying [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) to the UI widget [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779896/check-if-datapicker-is-open)).

However, you can solve your problem by binding to the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event:

```
$(".showCalendar").toggle(function() {
    $("#weekDate").datepicker("show");
}, function() {
    $("#weekDate").datepicker("hide");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work when the calendar is shown from the toggle button and hidden from input blur: next toggle tries to hide it again thus making the button "miss" a click.

Answer (score 10):

You can check visibility of widget and toggle widget as following:

```
$(".dp-icon").click(function (event) {
    var visible = $(".has-dp").datepicker("widget").is(":visible");
    $(".has-dp").datepicker(visible ? "hide" : "show");
})
```

Comment: Worked for me except `.has-dp` is `#weekDate` as per original post, i.e. the id of your input

Comment: Thanks buddy it realy helps.